# Pen testing your MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, password-protection, penetration-testing

Here are some the commonly known practices for securing an MVC application:

- Encode your output
- Parameterize your SQL
- Test your search backwards and forward
- 1 way hash passwords
- Lock out accounts or limit login attempts
- Use code based impersonation when accessing the file system
- Access SQL with a locked down username
- Use Honey-pots or captchas for form submissions to counter bots

If there are any I missed or misstated please feel free to contribute.

What other techniques/best practices do you use or think about when pen testing your own software. What do you do to "kick the tires" before taking a applications live.

What pen testing services or software do you use if any?

Comment: I suggest you community wiki this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All methods that use modelbinding should be secured with whitelists or blacklists on bindable properties.

```
string[] allowedProperties = new[]{ "Title", "Description"};
UpdateModel(myObject, allowedProperties);
```

or

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Title,Description")] MyObject object )
{

}
```

This is of course to prevent crafted requests from attempting to update/manipulate your objects in ways that weren't intended.

Answer (score 3):

Your list is good, although it is a bit vague.  For instance md4 is a one way hash,  but its extremely insecure as i can generate a collision on my desktop in less than a day. sha256 with a large salt value is a more secure approach.  (I know even this is description incomplete,  don't flame)

There is never a catch all security check list that will work across the board.  Specific applications can have specific vulnerabilities.  Sometimes these flaws can be logic errors that really don't have a classification.

The [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) web application vulnerabilities is an excellent resource that you should study.  Most notably you are missing XSRF on your list which can be a devastating attack.   There are a large number of "sink" based attacks which you have not listed.  For instance what if an attacker could pass in a path of his choice to fopen?  [A Study In Scarlet](http://www.securereality.com.au/studyinscarlet.txt)  goes over many of these attacks against PHP.

Answer (score 1):

All of your suggestions apply to any web application, not just MVC applications.

An MVC-specific suggestions would be something like "skinny controllers, fat models".